# Formal proof for an algorithmic problem of Alice and Bob

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, puzzle

The problem statement is-Eve is a beginner stand-up comedian. Her first show gathered a grand total of two spectators: Alice and Bob.

Eve prepared a1+a2+a3+a4 jokes to tell, grouped by their type:

type 1: both Alice and Bob like them;

type 2: Alice likes them, but Bob doesn't;

type 3: Bob likes them, but Alice doesn't;

type 4: neither Alice nor Bob likes them.

Initially, both spectators have their mood equal to 0. When a spectator hears a joke he/she likes, his/her mood increases by 1. When a spectator hears a joke he/she doesn't like, his/her mood decreases by 1. If the mood of a spectator becomes negative (strictly below zero), he/she leaves.

When someone leaves, Eve gets sad and ends the show. If no one leaves, and Eve is out of jokes, she also ends the show.

Thus, Eve wants to arrange her jokes in such a way that the show lasts as long as possible. Help her to calculate the maximum number of jokes she can tell before the show ends.

Here is the problem link - https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1792/B

I have spent quite some time over this problem, but I am not able prove some observations formally in this problem. I get that it is always optimal to select the type 4 operation in the last and type 1 operation in the first it is intuitively clear, however how do I show this formally? I was thinking on using some exchange arguments but wasn't able to construct the argument. Moreover, what should be the strategy to maximize the number of jokes?
Thanks

Comment: Please write the problem here and don't provide links to it.

Comment: Since both Alice and Bob start with zero mood, starting with any joke from types $2,3,4$ will make one of them leave immediately. Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: Another way to interpret the problem. You have a collection of arrows of equal length: $a_1 \nearrow, a_2 \searrow, a_3 \nwarrow, a_4 \swarrow$. Starting from the origin on a $y-x$ graph, what is the longest path of arrows (including overlaps) that you can make while staying in the first quadrant.

Comment: @TonyMathew I see, but how can we claim that  it will always better use the a1 arrows first then some other arrows except for the very first move using this interpretation?

Comment: @ChrisLewis I think it implies that we must select the a1 type of joke first but only that moment, what after that?

Comment: Is there any reason to think that there is only one possible order of jokes that maximizes the number of jokes told?

Comment: @paw88789 No,there might be many possible order of jokes with the same number of jokes

Comment: "Never use someone else's code, read the tutorials or communicate with other person during a virtual contest." "When you take part in individual contests, don't talk about the problems with other contestants, don't use somebody else's code or insert it into your solutions. If the contest is a team one, discuss the tasks only with the teammates."

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is a problem of very long back contest, I was just practising this problem.

Comment: The problem says "Finished" in the top right, so I think commenting should be okay.  Anyway, a relatively easy way to prove what you ask is to show that if S is a valid sequence of jokes, then S prefixed by and a_1 is also a valid sequence, and also so is S prefixed by an a_1 with any other a_1 removed from the original S.  To put another way, inserting or moving an a_1 joke to the start never invalidates a sequence.